# Send multiple email with time interval by PHP

Tags: php, email, foreach, sleep

i have a lot of email addresses. i choose the email that i want to send by checkbox form. actually, i can send its in one time. but, i little worry if it'll be spam. so, i want to send that emails one by one with interval between and the email sent only one, not twice. i use foreach and sleep but always fail. this is my code :

```
$citine = $_POST['kotanya'];
$siap = implode(", ", $_POST['kotanya']);
$max_loop=1;
$count = 0;
foreach($siap as $to) {
   $hasilnye = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   sleep(60);
   $count++;
   if($count==$max_loop) break;
}
if ($hasilnye > 0) {
   header( 'Location: http://google.com' ) ;
 } else {
echo "Gagal maning";
}
```

anybody can help me?

Comment: **always fail**, is there any fail message?

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). that the fail message..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using checkbox with `name="kotanya[]"`

So `$_POST['kotanya']` is an array. use it in foreach

Code:

```
foreach($_POST['kotanya'] as $to) {
   echo $to;
}
```

Comment: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: @kepo what is your `$_POST['kotanya']`

Comment: i use <input type="checkbox" name="kotanya[]" value="abcd@xyz.com"> to choose the email that i want to sent. i don't want to send them all because worry about spam.

Comment: No need to explode nor implode then, because it's already an array! Just loop through it!

Comment: `$siap = $_POST['kotanya'];` should do it.

Comment: Well, better have it twice than have nothing! haha

Comment: thank u for all of u guys.. ok, for the example the final code like this :

Comment: <?php
include 'dbconnect.php';

$judul = $_POST['judul'];
$materi= $_POST['materi'];
$citine = $_POST['kotanya'];
$siap = implode(", ", $_POST['kotanya']);

$to = "$siap";
$subject = "$judul";
$message = "$materi";
$headers  = "...";

$hasilnye = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($hasilnye > 0) {
header( 'Location: http://google.com ) ;
} else {
echo "Gagal maning";

?><br/> how can i send the Email 1 dan Email 2 with five minutes interval between?